# Run mochajs asynchronously (AMD-like)

Tags: javascript, requirejs, mocha.js

Can I load mocha module asynchronously in browser? I can do it for sure with chai. Is there any workaround to make mocha work in amd-like style ?

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/scripts",
    paths: {
        "mocha": "framework/mocha",
        "chai": "framework/chai",
        "first": "custom/first"
    }
});

require(['first', 'mocha', 'chai'], function (first, mocha, chai) {
        first.echo();

        console.log('something');
        console.log('something');

        mocha.ui('tdd');
        var assert = chai.assert;

        suite('"Home" Page Tests', function () {
            test('page should contain link to contact page', function () {
                assert($('a[href="/contact"]').length);
            });
        });

        mocha.run();

        console.log('whatever');
    });
```

in the code sample above `first` and `chai` work fine, while `mocha` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocha is not AMD-aware so if you are going to load Mocha using RequireJS, you need a `shim` for it. Here is an `index.html` file that contains a minimal example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xhtml; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link href="node_modules/mocha/mocha.css" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>
    <script>
      require.config({
          paths: {
              mocha: 'node_modules/mocha/mocha',
          },
          shim: {
              mocha: {
                 exports: "mocha",
              }
          },
      });

      require(["mocha"], function (mocha) {
        mocha.setup("bdd");
        it("foo", function () {});
        mocha.run();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You need to have run `npm install requirejs mocha` in the same directory where `index.html` is located.

In cases where I want to be able to use the `Mocha` constructor I use this `shim` instead:

```
  shim: {
      mocha: {
          exports: "mocha",
          init: function () { return {mocha: mocha, Mocha: Mocha }; }
      }
  },
```